# Error when start Phonegap project on Android device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a problem...After the build of my project PhoneGap, I want to run the it on my device with this command:

> cordova run android

When I run this command I receive this error:

> WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator

So run the emulator...I woun't the emulator, it's very slow...I Enable USB debugging on my device...Where is the problem? Also I want use the library of AngularJs...Where must I put the library? Thanks!

Comment: run the command 'adb devices' from the command line to see if it's properly recognizing your device. You may also want to run 'cordova run android --verbose' to see if an error pops up.

Comment: C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\hello>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

Comment: Looks like it's not recognizing your device. What usb connection setting are you using? I had to switch my connection to "media device". Also, what type of phone do you have?

Comment: I resolve the problem...I didn't install the USB drive on my pc...windows...XD

Comment: that's what I figured haha, best of luck with PhoneGap!